# How to split datagrid's itemssource into multiple datagrids wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Is it possible to split itemssource into two datagrids? For example if I have an itemssource with 200 records binded to one datagrid, i want to show 20 records in that datagrid and then for another 20 records, to make a new datagrid with the same column headers and binding but with different records. Then for new 20 records i want the 3rd datagrid and so on.
Now this is just an example, all I want to know is if it's possible to split itemssource like this?

Answer (score 1):

From a WPF point of view, your question seems quite redundant. In WPF, we work with data rather than UI objects, so we would data bind a data collection to the `CollectionControl.ItemsSource` property. With this in mind, your question (as I understand it from your brief description) is asking 'Can I split a collection of data items in two and bind each to a `DataGrid`?' The answer to that is of course, yes.

---

UPDATE >>>

So what you're *actually* asking is '*How can I page my data in WPF?*'. The answer to that is of course completely different to that of your *actual* question. It's a long story, but to keep it short, there are many articles online that will show you how to page your data using a WPF `DataGrid`. For example, you can find a detailed article on the 
[WPF DataGrid Custom Paging and Sorting](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1368/wpf-datagrid-custom-paging-and-sorting.aspx) page of NullSkull.com.

Comment: Well yes I want to split a collection into parts, but for each part I want to make a new datagrid and bind it to specific part. As I said I would like to indicate maximum items per datagrid, so if my collection doesn't go beyond that limit I want to have only one datagrid. So how to do this? Any suggestion?

Comment: I already have some paggination, but I'm only pagginating one datagrid. So what I can't figure out is how to split my collection and make new datagrids. That's what I need to do. I need same headers and columns binding but different itemssource for each datagrid.

Comment: Do you find solution ? Now, I have same question : )

Answer (score 0):

I make a example for this idea.
I used CustomControl.

You can modify what you want : )

Here is files.
https://github.com/bidasknakayama/SpilitDataGrid

[image]

My custom control is extended with Control.
if I have more knowledge which can extended with DataGrid,
it will be better control, but sorry. My knowledge is not good.
but it is enough useful.